# Linear Algebra requirement Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am interested in the extent of knowledge of Linear Algebra required for Spivak's *Calculus on Manifolds*.
More precisely, in the first problems in his book they reference norm preservation and inner-product preservation with regard to linear transformations and matrices.

I had done Lang's *Intro to Linear Algebra* but I don't feel like I learned enough to be able to handle the assumed knowledge in Spivak's book. 
I could work through Lang's *Linear Algebra* if I need to in order to gain the necessary background since I seem to have not gained it from the introductory book.

Does this seem like it would be a good book to prepare me? Perhaps others would be more suitable? I also had Strang's *Linear Algebra and It's Applications*

Comment: A lot of time is wasted reading books cover to cover. Whatever you don't understand in Spivak's book it will probably be readily available in any 'good' linear algebra book (as Lang). Just read and look up what you need to.